# Using App Engine Datastore outside of main.py

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the App Engine datastore in my application outside of the bounds of one of the request handler pages (like main.py or the other files you can specify in app.yaml). Is this possible? When I try to run it, it says my database model does not have a method "put" associated with it, but it has no problems when I run it from a script connected to CGI and request handling (like main.py or any other .py files I declare similarly in app.yaml). Do you know what I can do to add CGI to those pages without adding request handling? Thanks!

Edit my code:

users.py file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, webapp


class User(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
```

---

main.py file

```
from user import *

class CreateHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        u = User()
        u.email = "email@email.com"
        u.password = "mypass"
        u.put()
```

---

It gives me this error:
  File "........./main.py", line 75, in get
    u.put()
AttributeError: User instance has no attribute 'put'

Comment: Thanks @systempuntoout I just did!

Comment: 'User' is also the name of a class in the `google.appengine.api.user` module. Are you perhaps importing that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the datastore from other scripts. You don't have to add request handling to them, that can stay in your main script. Eg., you can do something like this:

**app.yaml:**

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

**main.py:**

```
from SectionHandlers import * # This imports classes from SectionHandlers.py

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ("/section1/.*", Section1Handler), # Map requests to handlers
    ("/section2/.*", Section2Handler),
], debug=True)
```

**SectionHandlers.py:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, webapp

class Section1Handler(BlogHandler):

def get(self):

    # Code using 'db' here
```

Comment: It still isn't working @DanTup This is what I'm Trying:from google.appengine.ext import db, webapp

import hashlib

class User(db.Model):
 email = db.EmailProperty()
 password = db.StringProperty()